# Can't terminate a Java .txt writing program

Tags: java, file-io

For a java homework assignment, I need to create a program that reads and writes .txt files. I have been able to create a method that reads a .txt file. However I am having difficulty in creating the write method. Below is the code for my write method (based on the FileOutput Class found here: http://www.devjavasoft.org/SecondEdition/SourceCode/Share/FileOutput.java).

The method successfully creates the .txt file and accepts user input, however I can not work out how to terminate the process and save the file. I thought a while loop would do the job, however when I satisfy the condition in the While loop, the loop doesn't end. I am sure there is a problem with my while condition logic, yet I can not see what is causing this to be an infinite loop.

```
public String chooseFileOutput(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the file directory for the output of the chosen txt");
    System.out.println("For Example: /Users/UserName/Downloads/FileName.txt");
    ///Users/ReeceAkhtar/Desktop/GeoIPCountryWhois.csv
    final String fileNameOUT = sc.nextLine();
    return fileNameOUT;
    }

public void writeTXT(final String fileNameOUT){
    FileOutput addData = new FileOutput (fileNameOUT);
    String newData = null;

    System.out.println("Enter text. To finish, enter 'EXIT'");

    while(!(newData == "EXIT")){
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        addData.writeString(newData = input.nextLine());
        System.out.println("MARKER");
    } 
    addData.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use the `equals()` method for String value comparisons. `==` is for object reference comparisons. And that is the reason the condition in the `while()` loop never evaluates to `false` and the program doesn't terminate.

```
while(!"EXIT".equals(newData)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are using the "==" operator for string value comparisons.  In Strings, that operator tests whether the two Strings on either side are the same object, and will return false when they are different objects with the same value.  You should use the equals() method, "EXIT".equals(newData)

Answer (score 0):

There is no assignment statement to retrieve scanner input, so it's no wonder that your loop is infinitive; `newData` is null for the duration of the program. You need a `newData = input.nextLine();`.

Another thing, you can't pass an assignment statement to a method; I'm surprised you aren't getting compile errors actually.

Answer (score 0):

java function for string comparison is "string.equals()"
So change the while loop with this code.

`while("EXIT".equals(newData)==false) {.....`